# Programming in Mathematica

Tags: programming

I am new Mathematica. I used Mupad in Matlab to write many codes. The notebook in Mupad in Matlab is convenient. But I found that Mathematica has some advantages. Therefore I would like to translate some Mupad codes to Mathematica.

The codes have many new defined functions. In the notebook of Mathematica, there are many outputs and the codes are separated far from each other. This is not very convenient if the program is large. Usually how people write programs in Mathematica if the programs are very large? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can separate a large project into packages. See the [Setting Up Wolfram Language Packages](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages.html) tutorial and the [Package Development](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PackageDevelopment.html) guide.

Comment: Any output can be repressed. You can, (if you want) do the entire code in one notebook cell.